# JDBC SQLite: Retrieval Operation - loops without stopping?|

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, while-loop, return

My program gives user control to do any CRUD Operations
on a Sqlite database.

However,my method to "Search for one vehicle" outputs the query multiple times until I get an exception, which points at the return statement.

Connection

[image]

Return statement

[image]

---------------------Here below is what I have done/looked/attempted:

1. While loop:I attempted to: "to set the condition false then true".
   "set condition with integer to loop limited number of times". They
   both output same exception.
2. Return statement: There no other expression/variable i can put into
   the return statement. I have no idea because the method is based on
   a class, so it must return that objects class.

**What I am doing wrong for it to loop continuously?**

[The method with exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnjJt.png)
DAO Class:

```
 import java.sql.SQLException;  
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;   
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    public class CasualDAO {

    private static Connection getDBConnection(){

            Connection dbConnection=null;
            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
            try{
                String dbURL="jdbc:sqlite:casual.sqlite";
                dbConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
                return dbConnection; 
            }catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return dbConnection;

        }

    public Casual getCasual(int c) throws SQLException{

        Connection dbConnection=null;
        Statement statement=null;
        ResultSet result= null;
        String query="SELECT * FROM casual WHERE id="+c+";";

        try{
            dbConnection=getDBConnection();
            statement= dbConnection.createStatement();

            System.out.println(query);
            result=statement.executeQuery(query);

            while(result.next()){

            System.out.println(result.getInt("id")+result.getString("first_name")+result.getString("last_name")+result.getString("adress"));

            }}catch(SQLException e){
                   e.getMessage();}
           finally{
              if(result!=null){
                    result.close();
              }
              if(statement!=null){
                 statement.close();
              }
              if(dbConnection!=null){
                 dbConnection.close();
              } 
         }
        return getCasual(c);

    }



    }
```

Controller:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Control {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CasualDAO thevehicle= new CasualDAO();

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Crud Operations");
        System.out.println( "Enter operation"); 
        System.out.println("Search = 1 "+"Insert = 2 "+"Delete = 3 "+"Update 
        = 4 ");
        String operation=in.next();

        if(operation.equals("1")){
            try{
            thevehicle.getCasual(1);
            }catch(SQLException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why is `return getCasual(c);` that part there? You're recursively calling `getCasual`, with no other return statements in that method.

Comment: The method type is "Casual" which is from the class. Would i need to create an object of "Casual" first in the method, and then store the output so i can return "casual" type?

Comment: Okay. It now displays once. I created an object in the method of type casual. First set to null, and then later override it with "new Casual(id, firstname, lastname,adress)" with the parameters. Then in the controller, I created another "casual" object, this time containing the casualDao.getCasual(1). 1 stands for the particular id in the query. I appreciate the insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create an object from class in the method and store your parameters there.Do the same in the controller except adding the parameters**

I created an object in the method of type casual called ("Casual cass=null"). Its first set to null because its not used immediately. Then, in the "while loop", its overriden with **"new Casual(id, firstname, lastname,adress)"**,this time containing the parameters.

In the controller, I created another "Casual" object, this time containing the casualDao.getCasual(1). 1 stands for the particular id in the query.

```
public Casual getCasual(int c) throws SQLException{

    Connection dbConnection=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet result= null;
    Casual cass=null;
    String query="Select * from casual WHERE id="+c+";";

    try{
        dbConnection=getDBConnection();
        statement= dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(query);
        result=statement.executeQuery(query);
       // Boolean test=result.next();
        while(result.next()){

                      int id =result.getInt("id");
                      String first_name =result.getString("first_name");
                      String last_name=result.getString("last_name");
                      String adress =result.getString("adress");
                      cass= new Casual(id,first_name,last_name,adress);
                      System.out.println(cass);
```

Controller:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Control {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CasualDAO case= new CasualDAO();
        Casual cass=null;

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Crud Operations");
        System.out.println( "Enter operation"); 
        System.out.println("Search = 1 "+"Insert = 2 "+"Delete = 3 "+"Update = 4 ");
        String operation=in.next();

        if(operation.equals("1")){
            try{
            cass=case.getCasual(1);
            }catch(SQLException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Mark's question,triggered this thought process in my mind, thanks.